# CSS scale divs in float layout

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want to create an automatic scaling layout without using the height property. I use a float layout between two divs, as shown in the image. The boxes in the middle have content of different size and I want the boxes to scale in such way, that all have the same height.

[image: Picturey picture]

Comment: Are your columns using a fluid width, and will you be using different backgrounds for each of the columns?

Comment: I shoudlve given more info. IE 7 should be supportet, so IE 7 isnt doable without those js hacks for child selectors. My current solution is min-height, but I felt that this can be done more scalable. Columns width is fixed due to a given column Layout. This css tricks article is basically exactly what I wanted, thanks Ian. I will go this way, when supporting legacy browsers become obsolete or I may use the js which lets me use the newer selectors in IE 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [reading this](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) article at css-tricks.

My favorite choice is probably the one taken from Paul Irish's blog at [HTML5Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/) - however it does rely on modern browsers. I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bZ8c/) based on his code:

**CSS**

```
.box {
  /* basic styling */
  width: 100%;
  height: 95px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  font: 14px Arial;
  /* flexbox setup */
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: box;
  box-orient: horizontal;
}

.box > div {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
}

/* our colors */
.box > div:nth-child(1){ background : #FCC; }
.box > div:nth-child(2){ background : #CFC; }
.box > div:nth-child(3){ background : #CCF; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
</div>
```

However **note** this won't work with legacy browsers, and if you're targeting those, I suggest you just adopt a table layout.

Comment: A link alone is a bad answer...(it can break) perhaps try summarizing what you think is best and/or post some short markup examples.

Comment: I agree with you, and I'd like to give some more assistance, however I suppose the article presents you with a number of solutions for different issues (such as if the columns are variable width, and backgrounds are needed), and I'm not sure that was articulated in the question. I'll probe for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zgzet/).

What I basically do, is use the `position:absolute` in combination with the `top` and `bottom` CSS property to force the inner div to take full height.

HTML:

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="middle"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
}

#top{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
}

#bottom{
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

#middle{
    width: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    background: gray;
}
```

Comment: see comment on Ian's answer... instead post the relevant parts of the markup in your answer.

Comment: Is this what he's asking for? I think he's asking how he can have 3-columns of equal height.

Comment: you can add columns if you'd like, but this is the main functionality needed for the picture shown in the question. If you want more just copy paste the middle div and float them.

Comment: No, I think if you look at the "Scale?" comment you'll see that that's what he's after.

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height`. Examples of this property are provided below.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530815%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

place the middle one in a div 
and make the three divs inside it and give them height 100%