# increase div heights based on the other div height

Tags: html, css

I am having one main Div,With in that i placed 3 divs (left ,center,right). My requirement is, When ever center div increases height automatically left and right divs height should be increased as same as middle one.I put total effort on this task,But i am unable to do.Please let me know which CSS properties should be used.Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/parsanamoni/ZkXak/)

```
<div class="mainDiv">
<div class="left">Left</div>
<div class="center">Center</br>Center<br/>Center<br/></div>
<div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give `bottom: 0` to `.left` and `.right`.

Comment: how about remove `postion`, add `display: table` to **mainDiv** and `display: table-cell; height: 100%;` to **left**,**center** and **right**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/pfqpR/

```
 .mainDiv { 
      height: auto;
 }
 .left, .right { 
      height: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/ZkXak/2/

CSS

```
     .mainDiv{ position: relative;}
    .left{ position: absolute;background:red; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100px;

        float: left;

        z-index: 100;
        height:100%;
    }

.right{ position: absolute;background:blue; right: 0; top: 0; width: 100px; height:100%; }
.center{ margin: 0 100px;background:green;  height:100%;}
```

[CSS scale divs in float layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17401134/css-scale-divs-in-float-layout/17401233#17401233)

Try this Demo also

http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

Answer (score 0):

Used to `bottom :0;` **according** to `@Mr_Green`

As like this

```
.mainDiv{ position: relative; height: auto;}
.left{ position: absolute;background:red; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100px; bottom:0;}
.right{ position: absolute;background:blue; right: 0; top: 0; width: 100px;bottom:0; }
.center{ margin: 0 100px;background:green; }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pfqpR/1/)**

Answer (score -1):

You can user javascript for this get the height of center div and set to left and right div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // get height of center div
    var heightCenterDiv =  document.getElementById('id').clientHeight;

    //set height of left and right div
    document.getElementById('leftdiv -id').style.height = heightCenterDiv+"px";
    document.getElementById('right -id').style.height = heightCenterDiv+"px";
</script>
```

for you code you can use class instead of div id.

Comment: Why this the best answer? Do not use js for trivial things